# How can I auto-toggle 'paste' upon pasting without a toggling key in vim?

Tags: vim, copy-paste

Here's what I have in .vimrc, which isn't working (for Mac):

```
inoremap <D-V> <Esc>:set paste<CR>i<D-V><Esc>:set nopaste<CR>i 
nnoremap <D-V> :set paste<CR>i<D-V><Esc>:set nopaste<CR>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a bad idea, You should learn to use `p`, `P`, `"<register>p` and `"<register>P` instead.

Comment: I know how to use `"+p`. For some reason it doesn't seem to work on Mac, though.

Comment: Yes it works perfectly, in MacVim.

Comment: Other things don't work for me in MacVim.

Comment: So I use terminal `vim`.